# JQuery Cookie values not maintained while moving from http to https

Tags: jquery

I am creating cookie using jquery, please see below code:

```
var divID = $(link).next(".open-block-holder").find("div:first").attr("id");
$('#panelOpen').val(divID);                             
$.cookie('currentPanelOpen', divID);
```

the above Cookies 'currentPanelOpen' is been created in HTTP page, now on my login click I am reloading whole page in HTTPS for security reasons. The problem is that my cookie 'currentPanelOpen' value is not maintained while it is moving to HTTPS page. (happening only for first time, once gone to https mode and again coming back to http page and doing above step works fine)

Surprisingly, If I directly open the page in HTTPS mode then the value is maintained and my clicked panel is opened.

Please suggest!

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried make it secure like this: `$.cookie('currentPanelOpen', divID, { expires: 2, path: '/', domain: 'yourwebsite.com', secure: true });` ? ([source](http://webhole.net/2010/07/10/jquery-cookies-example/))

Comment: Yes,I did in that case my cookies was not created

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because there is a fundamental difference between a cookie created in a normal HTTP session and a cookie created in an HTTPS session. The latter is encrypted much like the connection as well (because it would be a giant security hole if your connection is encrypted but any data stored on your machine weren't)

I have 2 suggestions, one which might not work:

1) Use the cookie call like this (provided you're using the one I'm familiar with)

```
$.cookie('the_cookie', 'the_value', { expires: 7, path: '/', domain: 'jquery.com', secure: true });
```

And try to set the domain to https (creating 2 cookies, one for http, one for https) or by trying the "secure" flag, true/false etc. Or

2) Use jQuery's AJAX ability to create a user session in PHP (http://www.reynoldsftw.com/2009/03/using-jquery-and-ajax-to-create-php-sessions/) which then should maintain the "panelOpen" div by way of either opening it up once it reloads in the document.ready call or in the code itself... also making sure to set the https cookie again.

Comment: What do you mean by "And try to set the domain to https (creating 2 cookies, one for http, one for https) or by trying the "secure" flag, true/false etc.",how to do that?

Comment: $.cookie('the_cookie', 'the_value', { expires: 7, path: '/', domain: 'https://jquery.com', secure: true/false(toggle this) });

Comment: Any reason why my cookie is not created if I am putting above syntax, $.cookie("currentPanelOpen",divID,{ expires: null, path: '/', domain: 'dxbmiwwekdev1', secure: true })...if I am removing my domain it is creating the cookies, however my problem still persist