# HTTP Cookies and Ajax requests over HTTPS

Tags: ajax, http, cookies, https

I know this has been asked before in various forms, but I can't seem to get around the problem. 
I have tried using both jQuery and the native JS API to make the Ajax requests.

My situation is the following (see attached diagram):

1. Browser makes HTTP request
2. Server responds and sets persistent Cookie
3. Browser makes HTTP Ajax request, Cookie is there alright
4. Server responds as expected, updates Cookie
5. Browser makes HTTPS Ajax request, Cookie is not there anymore (?!)
6. Server gives "default" response, since there is no Cookie (unintended behaviour)

Before anybody starts a lecture on cross-domain requests let me state a couple of things:

- I know that this is a cross-domain request (different protocol), and that's why the Server sets the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header in the response (and I am using Chrome and Firefox, both of which support [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing))
- What I also know, though, is that the HTTP cookie ought to be manageable over HTTPS (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2163828/reading-cookies-via-https-that-were-set-using-http)) since the host is the same
- (EDIT) The cookie is properly set for the general domain (e.g. .domain.ext) and neither the HttpOnly nor the Secure flags are set

So, why, why, why doesn't the browser pass on the cookie when making the HTTPS Ajax call? Any ideas? I am about to lose my mind...

```
     +-----------+ HTTP Request     +-----------+
     |Browser    |+---------------->|Server     |
     +-----------+                  +-----------+

                   HTTP Response
                  <----------------+
                   Set-cookie

                   Ajax HTTP Req.
                  +---------------->
                   Cookie (OK)

                   HTTP Response
                  <----------------+
                   Set-cookie (OK)

                   Ajax HTTPS Req.
                  +---------------->
                   No Cookie (!!!)
```

Comment: Capture the HTTP request dump and check if any of the `secure` and `http-only` flags are set in the `Set-Cookie` statement. That would at least be a good place to start from.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5441836/jquery-cookie-values-not-maintained-while-moving-from-http-to-https looks like this is a deliberate limitation.

Comment: Thanks, I had already read it, but it does not help at all. First, it says that an https cookie is encrypted, which is only true when in transit (otherwise the browser would not be able to access its data). The explanation given is also against the cookie specification, AFAIK.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

Ok, found the solution to the cookie problem.

See [XHR specs](https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/#the-withcredentials-attribute), [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) and [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2870371/why-jquery-ajax-not-sending-session-cookie).

The solution to have the cookies sent when switching protocol and/or subdomain is to set the `withCredentials` property to `true`.

E.g. (using jQuery)

```
 $.ajax( {
   /* Setup the call */
   xhrFields: {
     withCredentials: true
   }
 });
```

Comment: Awesome. You found the answer yourself.  Thanks for sharing. So many posts when people find the answer and don't share. Kudos NeXuS.

Comment: Unfortunately I wasn't able to make it work nonetheless... :D

Comment: thanks, this worked for me after 2 days of trying to figure out why

Answer (score 0):

Document.cookie and Ajax Request does not share the cookie. Otherwise, ajax can't access the cookies from document.cookie or the response headers. They can only be controlled by the remote domain.

If you first get response including cookie from server by ajax, Since that you can request ajax communication with cookie to server.

For this case, you write such as below code (jQuery)

```
 $.ajax({
      xhrFields : {
           withCredentials : true
      }
 });
```

See [this article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Requests_with_credentials) and [demo](http://arunranga.com/examples/access-control/credentialedRequest.html)