# How to set cookie value with AJAX request?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-mobile, cookies

I want to set a cookie value on an AJAX request but the code below doesn't work.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",    
    url: "http://example.com",
    cache: false,
    setCookies: "lkfh89asdhjahska7al446dfg5kgfbfgdhfdbfgcvbcbc dfskljvdfhpl",
    crossDomain: true,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
        alert(data);
    });
```

How can I set cookies in the header?

Comment: There simply isn't `setCookies` option in the settings.

Comment: what are you trying to do..?

Comment: You should set cookie earlier in javascript and then send the request. Headers will contain your cookie on ajax request. Use these functions to set and get cookie in JS: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Basically, ajax request as well as synchronous request sends your document cookies automatically. So, you need to set your cookie to document, not to request. However, your request is cross-domain, and things became more complicated. Basing on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10230341/http-cookies-and-ajax-requests-over-https/10249123), additionally to set document cookie, you should allow its sending to cross-domain environment:

```
type: "GET",    
url: "http://example.com",
cache: false,
// NO setCookies option available, set cookie to document
//setCookies: "lkfh89asdhjahska7al446dfg5kgfbfgdhfdbfgcvbcbc dfskljvdfhpl",
crossDomain: true,
dataType: 'json',
xhrFields: {
    withCredentials: true
},
success: function (data) {
    alert(data);
});
```

Comment: And what if I want to, sort of, fake a cookie and send it without setting it? After all, cookie is just a header, c'mon! :)

Comment: @TomášZato According to [XHR specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#the-setrequestheader()-method) you can't do it. (See point 5 `Terminate these steps if header is a case-insensitive match` ... `Cookie` ... `The above headers are controlled by the user agent to let it control those aspects of transport. This guarantees data integrity to some extent.`). I believe you still can *fake* a cookie *by setting* it before request and deleting on `complete` callback. I believe it's the most we can do in browser.

Comment: I ctually just reminded myself that javascript is single threaded, so setting a cookie and deleting it afterwards will not have negative results on other scripts.