# Calling a website and getting JSON information back

Tags: javascript, html, json

I am not too experienced in javascript on using API's and how to call websites and get information back. I have done this before in Java using HTTP objects and more. I am attempting to make an application where a user can type in a company stock name such as APPL and get back a ton of data like gains, losses, changes, etc. This shouldn't be that hard. I have a html/javascript file with an input textbox for the stock name. This part is easy. But after I tack on the stock name to the end of the URL by concatenation I don't know how to make the call and get the JSON information. There are examples of how to do this in other languages in the web page I am using but not for javascript. I am using this link as a tutorial:

```
 http://digitalpbk.com/stock/google-finance-get-stock-quote-realtime
```

Here is my javascript code so far: Again this is probably really simple to do. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated and is good to know in the future.

```
script type="text/javascript">

var submitButton = document.getElementById("submitButton");
submitButton.addEventListener('click', actionPerformed, false);

function actionPerformed(e)
{

    var textValue = document.getElementById("stockTextBox").value;
    var urlEncoded = "http://finance.google.com/finance/info?client=ig&q=NASDAQ:" + textValue.toString();


    for (var i = 0, len = urlEncoded.length; i < len; ++i) {
     var object = urlEncoded[i];
     confirm(object.toString());
 }

}


</script>
```

I just found the following code for using HTTP GET and tried it out but nothing happens when I click the submit button. Any suggestions on what to do or what's wrong???

```
 function httpGet(theUrl)
    {
    var xmlHttp = null;

    xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlHttp.open( "GET", theUrl, false );
    xmlHttp.send( null );
    return xmlHttp.responseText;
    }
```

Wow, this is turning out to be a lot more work then I had anticipated. Here is the URL string I am using in my code for yahoo finance. I can navigate to it in the browser and it works like a charm. For the life of me I cannot understand why this isn't working.

```
var urlEncoded = "http://www.finance.yahoo.com/webservice/v1/symbols/" + textValue.toString() + "/quote?format=json";
```

Comment: What you want is to make an AJAX request.

Comment: Could you please elaborate?

Comment: When you do figure out AJAX requests, you should try going to the URL you are requesting and make sure it works. ;) (I don't ever use AJAX requests without some sort of wrapper, so I couldn't tell you exactly how to do it)

Comment: Yes, the URL works in firefox without a problem. This wouldn't have anything to do with the same version policy in javascript would it?

Comment: Have a look at the chapter [HTTP Requests](http://eloquentjavascript.net/chapter14.html) of the Eloquent JavaScript book. There is a very good example how to create and use a XMLHTTPRequest object with JavaScript (AJAX is nothing fancy, but just an abbreviation for Asynchronous JavaScript And Xml). Oh and also i am not sure if the [Google Finance API is available anymore...](https://developers.google.com/finance/?csw=1). Maybe this is why it is not working...

Comment: Wow, totally didn't realize this. It looks like Yahoo Finance may be a good substitute.

Comment: The Google Finance API requires that a cookie is set, this may result in cross domain issues. This: http://finance.google.com/finance/info?client=iq&q=NASDAQ:GOOG returns a json string prepended with `//`.

Comment: I just tried yahoo finance and I'm getting the same problem. Nothing is coming back. I just pasted the URL I am using this time in the most recent edit. The bottom code.

Comment: It is definitely possible, though ;). I found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16851896/how-to-set-cookie-value-with-ajax-request that is relevant. The issue is that the page in the users browser is making connections to 2 separate servers yours and googles, which makes it crossdomain. Contrast this with the python script which is behaving as if it is a browser connecting to a single server (google).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try jQuery, google and download it.
It's a javascript framework that makes things allot simpler .

```
$.get( "http://yourur.com/file.php?parameter1=value1&parameter2=value2", function( data ) {
    //data now contains whatever it loaded from server
    console.log("Loaded from server :", data);
}, "json");
```