# Cross protocol cookie iFrame

Tags: javascript, http, cookies, https, xss

I have a web page on **http**://localhost/mySite/Page1.aspx that contains an iframe with src **https**://localhost/mySite/Page2.aspx.

Inside iframe page (Page2.aspx), i set cookie with JavaScript. How i can read that cookie on parent page (Page1.aspx)??? It looks like Page1 not sees the cookie that Page2 sets.

To set/read cookies, I use jQuery.Cookie plugin:

```
$.cookie('myKey', JSON.stringify(data), { expires: 1, path: '/', domain: 'localhost' });
```

BTW, if someone can give me an idea how to transfer data on client in such scheme, i will glad to know about it (Server pooling not a solution for me).
I found it works with sessionStorage / localStorage, but it works only in IE :(

Comment: Due to the Same Origin Policy, "I can't let you do that, Dave". Simply check [Wikiepdia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy#Origin_determination_rules): different protocols (HTTP & HTTPS) officially make your Page1 and Page2 come from different sources. See [this Bible amongst the cross-domain iframe communication techniques](http://softwareas.com/cross-domain-communication-with-iframes), and also [that elegant though complex technique](http://shouldersofgiants.co.uk/Blog/post/2009/08/17/Another-Cross-Domain-iFrame-Communication-Technique.aspx).

Comment: Also, in case you don't need backward compatibility with awkward fossils like MSIE, have some Google fun and go look for the new message-oriented inter-frame communication system introduced with HTML5 (window.postMessage() and the onMessage event). Cheers!

Comment: @StockOverflaw Thanks!! Its helped me a lot :) Do you know any framework that handles cross domain iframes/frames implementation? I started to write my own, but if it exists, why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: I don't know of any... However, a quick search of "cross domain communication library" gives some results (Ternarylabs' Porthole looks nice and easy to use, I just saw EasyXDM too that seems performance-oriented).

Comment: @StockOverflaw actually, based on links you provided me in your first comment, I'm done with my task, but I will review that libraries, maybe it will more flexible that mine. BTW, can you post an answer with the links, so I will mark it as "answer". Thanks again :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the question's comments:

The issue is due to the Same Origin Policy (SOP), which forbids contents of different sources from interfering with one another. *different sources* is not only based on the comparison of domains, it is also based on the protocol in use as it is [clearly shown on this Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy#Origin_determination_rules). Thus, `http://localhost` is a different origin to `https://localhost`.

In order to make these two sources able to communicate:

- [this link](http://softwareas.com/cross-domain-communication-with-iframes) perfectly describes the commonly used techniques (iframe proxies & URL polling), and intelligibly sums up the rules of the SOP in its paragraph "The Laws of Physics: what you can do with IFrames"
- [this other well-documented article](http://shouldersofgiants.co.uk/Blog/post/2009/08/17/Another-Cross-Domain-iFrame-Communication-Technique.aspx) (linked from the article above) merges the usual techniques into an elegant solution
- in case the targeted browsers are all HTML5-compliant (i.e. up-to-date-and-to-standards browsers, i.e. not most MSIE versions), this standard introduced a new inter-frame communication system with `window.postMessage()` and the `onMessage` event

There are also free pre-built solutions (which I didn't tested though), like [Ternarylabs' Porthole](http://ternarylabs.github.com/porthole/) or [EasyXDM](http://easyxdm.net/wp/).

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is completely correct. The cookies for which the secure attribute is not set to true, will be shared across the domain irrespective of the protocol in use.

The real problem for you is the jquery ignoring this aspect, which can be altered by specifying `secure=true` as a JSON attribute using `$.cookie('the_cookie', 'the_value', { expires: 7, path: '/', domain: 'jquery.com', secure: true });` as in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5441836/jquery-cookie-values-not-maintained-while-moving-from-http-to-https) question.