# cross site ajax using proxy not working

Tags: jquery

I am trying to do cross site ajax using tinyproxy as a reverse proxy. Here is the setup:

- A desktop system running gentoo linux. Ip address is x.x.x.x. Boa (web server, port 80) and tinyproxy (http proxy, port 8888) is running on this system.

Here are the test files:

======= a.html ======

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Ajax test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="a.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

======= a.js ========

```
$(document).ready( function() {

    function error_func()
    {
        alert("error occurred");
    }

    function ajax_func(data)
    {
        alert("ajax received");
    }

    $.get("http://x.x.x.x:8888/outside/xyz.txt", ajax_func).error(error_func);

});
```

I have configured tinyproxy so that http://x.x.x.x:8888/outside/ will go to http://www.outside.com/. I control that domain and I have placed a text file there, xyz.txt, with the "test string" in it.

Now, when I put the following url into firefox: x.x.x.x:8888/xyz.txt, everything works and I see the "test string" displayed in the browser window. But when I put x.x.x.x/a.html into firefox, I get the "error occurred" dialog box. I have tried this on IE, Safari, Firefox, and Chrome and I get the "error occurred" dialog in all of them.

Please note that I am aware of the "same origin policy", that's why I am using tinyproxy to get around that limitation.

I used wireshark on the gentoo linux machine to watch the traffic. Everything looks ok. I see an HTTP transaction between firefox and x.x.x.x, then I see an HTTP transaction between x.x.x.x and "outside" and finally another HTTP transaction between x.x.x.x and firefox. The HTTP 200 OK includes the "test string" as expected. But still, jquery isn't happy and I don't get the "ajax received" dialog box...

One thing I am suspecting is the HTTP "Server" header. The x.x.x.x system says "Server: Boa", but the final response has "Server: Apache". Would I be violating the same origin policy because of this difference?

Comment: BTW, I can't use JSONP, because on the real server that I will be working with (shoutcast), I don't have any control and they don't support JSONP for all their API's. This is just a simple test that I rigged up in order to establish a baseline. So if I am able to retrieve the xyz.txt file using jquery, the next step is making API calls to shoutcast to retrieve XML data using the same mechanism

Comment: maybe it's just a typo here on SO, but you talk about `x.x.x.x:8888/xyz.txt` when you manually test and `x.x.x.x:8888/outside/xyz.txt` in your javascript file. THAT isn't the error, right?

Comment: Hello Roman, yes that's a typo... I wasn't able to add full links (new user), so I had to mutilate things around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The same origin policy restricts access to the:

- same host
- same protocol
- **same port**

The same origin policy applies also to your case because you try to access `x.x.x.x:8888` from `x.x.x.x:80`.

you need to deliver the content also over the same port.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Any idea how I can run the web server and the http proxy on the same host with 80 being the incoming port?

Comment: @user1692262, it depends on your server technology and your demands... In PHP it could be as simple as `echo file_get_contents('http://www.outside.com/');`

Comment: Unfortunately target system is an embedded system running boa as the web server and the only serer technology available there is cgi. I am well versed is C/C++ development, so worst case I can use libcurl to implement the shoutcast api support. But the embedded CPU is already overloaded, so if possible, I want to use client PC CPU cycles to do all the shoutcast api work. I am also a noob in web stuff (html, js, jquery)

Answer (score 1):

Ajax communications must be made under these three conditions:

1. Same host
2. Same protocol
3. Same port

So technically you can't use an Ajax call when communicating between different ports, BUT there's a simple solution. You can ignore the prestated conditions if you define an Access-Control-Allow-Origin header allowing you to gain access from another host/protocol/port.

You'll have to make sure that your webpage is allowed access to your proxy via the correct header(s).

For more information I suggest you read this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP_access_control

Answer (score 0):

About a month ago, I asked almost the same question. You can find the answer here:
[Cross protocol cookie iFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12198166/cross-protocol-cookie-iframe)