# jQuery cookie not being passed from HTTPS page to another HTTPS page

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I am trying to send a cookie from one HTTPS page to another HTTPS page with jQuery cookies.

**I set the cookie like so one page 1:**

```
$.cookie('name', variable, { expires: 300 , secure:true});
```

**And then on the next page, I try to get it like so:**

```
console.log( $.cookie('name') );
```

No dice... is what I am trying to do illegal or immoral in some way?

If it helps, the pages are:
[Page 1](https://fieldedge.com.au/pricing-extended/?provider=webedge)

Page 2 can be reached by clicking on any of the "Try it Free" buttons.

Comment: Hmm, it looks good. Have you checked if the cookie is saved in the browsers cookies? :-)

Comment: yep, did a quick document.cookie, and it's not in there

Comment: Have you checked if the cookie is present using the developer tools of the browser? For Chrome, hit the F12 key, and then pick the Resources tab and it should be under Cookies.

Comment: yep, opened dev tools and just typed document.cookie in the console, and it's definitely not there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set cookie with domain path:

```
$.cookie('the_cookie', 'the_value', { expires: 7, path: '/', domain: 'jquery.com', secure: true });
```

**You can read that here:**

[JQuery Cookie values not maintained while moving from http to https](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5441836/jquery-cookie-values-not-maintained-while-moving-from-http-to-https)

**you can set and get cookie by javascript as well** that works fine on https server

`set cookie`:

```
document.cookie="username=John Doe";
```

`get cookie`:

```
var x = document.cookie;
```

`delete cookie`:

```
document.cookie = "username=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 UTC";
```

**you can get help from:**

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

Comment: No, that didn't work. I'm not trying to send from HTTP to HTTPS. I'm going from HTTPS to HTTPS.

Comment: have you try to set and get cookie via javascript not jquery

Comment: I tried to set and get cookie by javascript on https server and it works fine, it might help you. `document.cookie="username=John Doe";`

Comment: I don't think you've tested that properly. If you set that cookie on one page, and then go to another page (for example https://fieldedge.com.au/) then the cookie will not be there.

Comment: it has been tested by javascript, you can see that on my development server https://hestabit.in (first page), https://hestabit.in/test (second page)

Comment: I'm not sure why it wasn't working on my end. It just suddenly started working. With my code and yours. Very strange. Sorry that I'm unable to offer any more explanation than that.